# Get Node Numbers to Variable

Tags: beam, ansys

I am using Andys APDL.
I want to create Beam Element by entering Node numbers.

Nodes numbers selection is through option “by location“

Then I don’t know how use them in element creation command i.e. E,node#,node#.

Probably the selected nodes need be declared as variable and then variables need be used in element creation command. But I don’t know the syntax.

```
/NOPR   ! Suppress printing of UNDO process 
/PMACRO ! Echo following commands to log    
FINISH  ! Make sure we are at BEGIN level   
/CLEAR,NOSTART  ! Clear model since no SAVE found     
/REPLOT,RESIZE  
/PREP7  
!*  
ET,1,SOLID185   
ET,2,BEAM188
SECTYPE,   1, BEAM, CSOLID, , 0 
SECOFFSET, CENT 
SECDATA,0.25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 ! SMA Wire dia 0.5

!*  
!*  
MPTEMP,,,,,,,,  
MPTEMP,1,0  
MPDATA,EX,1,,140e3  
MPDATA,EY,1,,10e3   
MPDATA,EZ,1,,10e3   
MPDATA,PRXY,1,,.3   
MPDATA,PRYZ,1,,.3   
MPDATA,PRXZ,1,,.3   
MPDATA,GXY,1,,5e3   
MPDATA,GYZ,1,,5e3   
MPDATA,GXZ,1,,5e3 
MPTEMP,,,,,,,,  
MPTEMP,1,0  
UIMP,1,REFT,,,
MPDATA,ALPX,1,,0
MPDATA,ALPY,1,,0
MPDATA,ALPZ,1,,0

MPTEMP,,,,,,,,  
MPTEMP,1,0  
MPDATA,EX,2,,140e3  
MPDATA,EY,2,,10e3   
MPDATA,EZ,2,,10e3   
MPDATA,PRXY,2,,.3   
MPDATA,PRYZ,2,,.3   
MPDATA,PRXZ,2,,.3   
MPDATA,GXY,2,,5e3   
MPDATA,GYZ,2,,5e3   
MPDATA,GXZ,2,,5e3 
MPTEMP,,,,,,,,  
MPTEMP,1,0  
UIMP,2,REFT,,,
MPDATA,ALPX,2,,1e-4
MPDATA,ALPY,2,,1e-4
MPDATA,ALPZ,2,,1e-4

RECTNG,,70,,250,
FLST,5,4,4,ORDE,2   
FITEM,5,1   
FITEM,5,-4  
CM,_Y,LINE  
LSEL, , , ,P51X 
CM,_Y1,LINE 
CMSEL,,_Y   
!Element edge length = 1
LESIZE,_Y1,1, , , , , , ,1 
!*  
! Total thickness 1.2  
VOFFST,1,1.2, , 
! Active coordinate system is WP
CSYS,4 
wpoff,0,0,1.2
NUMCMP,ALL 
wpoff,0,0,-.3
VSBW,all, ,DELETE  
NUMCMP,ALL   
wpoff,0,0,-.3 
VSBW,all, ,DELETE  
NUMCMP,ALL
wpoff,0,0,-.3
VSBW,all, ,DELETE 
NUMCMP,ALL    


allsel

CSYS,0  
wpro,90.000000,,
CSWPLA,11,0,1,1,

VSEL,S, , ,1
VATT,       2, ,   1,       0
VSEL,S, , ,2
VATT,       1, ,   1,       11
VSEL,S, , ,3
VATT,       1, ,   1,       0
VSEL,S, , ,4
VATT,       1, ,   1,       11


/USER,  1   
/VIEW,  1, -0.428272868107    , -0.866717917167    ,  0.255699828911
/ANG,   1,   67.7726610751  
/REPLO  
/ZOOM,1,SCRN,0.529172,-0.207734,0.623620,-0.294604 
WPCSYS,-1,0 
/REPLOT
 
allsel

VSWEEP,1
VSWEEP,2
VSWEEP,4
VSWEEP,3

allsel

!Apply displacement on thickness areas and Uniform temperature with Pre-stress ON
/SOL
!*  
PSTRES,1
FLST,2,4,5,ORDE,4   
FITEM,2,4   
FITEM,2,9   
FITEM,2,13  
FITEM,2,18  
!*  
/GO 
DA,P51X,ALL,
TUNIF,1000, 

tol=.01
x1=10
x2=20
x3=30
x4=40
x5=50
x6=60

allsel
CSYS,4  
NSEL,s,LOC,x,x1-tol,x1+tol 
NSEL,a,LOC,x,x2-tol,x2+tol 
NSEL,a,LOC,x,x3-tol,x3+tol 
NSEL,a,LOC,x,x4-tol,x4+tol 
NSEL,a,LOC,x,x5-tol,x5+tol 
NSEL,a,LOC,x,x6-tol,x6+tol
NSEL,r,LOC,z,.3-tol,.3+tol
CM,SMAN,NODE ! Group SMA nodes as Component 
CMSEL,S,SMAN
nplot

/PREP7  
TYPE,   2   
MAT,       2
REAL,   
ESYS,       0   
SECNUM,   1 

/ZOOM,1,SCRN,0.170269,-0.876259,0.234494,-0.940468  
/AUTO,1 
/REP,FAST   
/VIEW,1,,,1 
/ANG,1  
/REP,FAST

! Create Beam Elements for SMA using nodes selected in Component "SMAN"
CMSEL,S,SMAN
nplot
```

Comment: Have you had a look at the APDL documentation found in _Help → Help Topics → Command reference_, as I assume you are talking about scripting? You may there browse the various commands, such as **N** and **E** which are relevant to your case in particular.

Comment: If you are new to the software, I will also suggest having a look at the _Introductory Tutorials_ found under _Help Topics_, as they will guide you through many helpful features.

Comment: @ToxicOwl The documentation for APDL or Command Manual do not cover the particular requirement which I have. 
The Nodes numbers need be stored as a variable.

Comment: Could you please specify to what nodes the nodes in your named selection should be connected. Perhaps you could provide a sketch of what you are trying to achieve. Do you want something like a reinforcement for the sheet? Should the nodes simply be connected along the y-direction?

Comment: At the end of my code, selected component, there are 6 columns of nodes. Consider one such column. Join its nodes, pair by pair to create beam element. But I want to select by APDL not through Graphical Picking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save a node number in different ways:

1. Define the number directly:

   ```
   N, NODE, X, Y, Z, THXY, THYZ, THZX
   ```

From the docs:

> NODE
> Node number to be assigned. A previously defined node of the same
> number will be redefined. Defaults to the maximum node number used +1.

That means you can define a node like this:

```
NODENUMBER = 999
N, NODENUMBER , 0, 0, 0
```

2. Get the last created node number:

   ```
   *GET, NODENUMBER, NODE, 0, NUM, MAX
   ```
3. Get node number by location:

   ```
    NODENUMBER = NODE(x,y,z)
   ```

> NODE(x,y,z) returns the number of the selected node nearest the x,y,z
> location (in the active coordinate system, lowest number for
> coincident nodes)

I adapted the vm1 example from the docs. When you know the nodal positions it looks like this:

```
/PREP7
ANTYPE,STATIC                  ! STATIC ANALYSIS
ET,1,LINK180
SECTYPE,1,LINK
SECDATA,1                  ! CROSS SECTIONAL AREA (ARBITRARY) = 1
MP,EX,1,30E6

N, ,0,0,0
N, ,0,4,0
N, ,0,7,0
N, ,0,10,0

NODE1 = NODE(0,0,0)
NODE2 = NODE(0,4,0)
NODE3 = NODE(0,7,0)
NODE4 = NODE(0,10,0)

E,NODE1 ,NODE2                          ! DEFINE ELEMENTS
EGEN,3,1,1                              ! Generates elements from an existing pattern
D,NODE1,ALL,,,NODE4,NODE3                  ! BOUNDARY CONDITIONS AND LOADING
F,NODE2,FY,-500
F,NODE3,FY,-1000
FINISH
/SOLU    
OUTPR,BASIC,1
OUTPR,NLOAD,1
SOLVE
FINISH
```

4. If you don't know the exact position of the nodes, you can loop through a selected set:

   ```
    /PREP7
    ANTYPE,STATIC                  ! STATIC ANALYSIS
    ET,1,LINK180
    SECTYPE,1,LINK
    SECDATA,1                  ! CROSS SECTIONAL AREA (ARBITRARY) = 1
    MP,EX,1,30E6

    N, ,0,0,0
    N, ,0,4,0
    N, ,0,7,0
    N, ,0,10,0

    NSEL,S,LOC,X,0             ! SELECT ALL NODES WITH X-COMPONENT 0. YOU HAVE TO SPECIFY THE RANGE WERE THE NODES ARE LOCATED. I STRONGLY RECOMMEND READING UP ON NSEL
    *GET,CURRN,NODE,0,NUM,MIN        ! GET MINIMUM NODE NUM IN VARIABLE CURRN
    *GET,NUM_OF_NODES,NODE,0,COUNT   ! GET NUM OF NODES
    NODE1 = CURRN
    IND = 1
    NUM_OF_NODES_1 = NUM_OF_NODES - 1
    *DO,J,1,NUM_OF_NODES_1
    IND = IND + 1
        *GET,CURRN,NODE,CURRN,NXTH   ! GET THE NODE NUMBER IN THE SET HIGHER THAN CURRN
        NODE%IND% = CURRN
    *ENDDO 

    E,NODE1 ,NODE2                          ! DEFINE ELEMENTS
    EGEN,3,1,1                              ! Generates elements from an existing pattern
    D,NODE1,ALL,,,NODE4,NODE3                  ! BOUNDARY CONDITIONS AND LOADING
    F,NODE2,FY,-500
    F,NODE3,FY,-1000
    FINISH
    /SOLU    
    OUTPR,BASIC,1
    OUTPR,NLOAD,1
    SOLVE
    FINISH
   ```

Comment: Still not clear to me so want to share whole APDL text here. 

How can I attach APDL text here?

Comment: Thanks but in my case beam elements will not use new nodes. 
Instead beam nodes will be based on ready-made mesh made through Volume meshing. 
Therefore I don’t have control on numbering of Volume Nodes. 
Maximum I could do was to selected “by location “ to pick volume nodes to be utilised in making Beam elements. 
But it needs graphical picking. 
I want to avoid graphical picking as nodes may be in hundreds

Comment: I changed my answer and added another option. If you indent text by four spaces and put new line in front it shows up like `this`

Comment: Do you want to create a beam spider, perhaps?

Comment: I have uploaded whole APDL text. 
Just run till the end and specific nodes for beam element creation